# Overriding method to pass a different set of delimiters to Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Few questions on over riding.

I am interiting a method `openRead` from another class, the method is to be overridden so that the scanner class uses the provided delimiter pattern, which is referenced. I need to make use of the scanner class useDelmiter method

method from another class

```
public boolean openRead() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
   sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    if (fileName != null)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

delimiter

```
protected final String DELIMITERS = "[\\s[^'a-zA-Z]]";
```

I'm at a loss to how i over ride this using the constant delimiter.

Comment: Three months and four previous questions, with respect you really, really should be formatting code correctly now rather than making othe people clean it up for you. To the right of the "Ask a Question" box there's a link labelled **How to Format**. Worth a read, it tells you exactly what to do in a quick easily-glanced-at list. The extended version is here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your title and question don't seem to match, or I might just be misunderstanding what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want the overridden version to use a different delimiter pattern for the `Scanner`? I suggest taking a look at the [Scanner API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6//docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29) as it documents how to use a different delimiter pattern.

```
public boolean openRead() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    boolean result = super.openRead();
    sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITERS);
    return result;
}
```

**edit**

Or perhaps you just don't know what overriding is in Java, and for that you should read more in the [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

But essentially, if you had some class:

```
public class ScannerUserParent
{
    protected Scanner sc;
    private String filename = null;

    // all that other stuff like constructors...

    public boolean openRead() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        if (fileName != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you subclass that class (or `extends`):

```
public class ScannerUserChild extends ScannerUserParent
{
    protected final String DELIMITERS = "[\\s[^'a-zA-Z]]";

    // stuff like constructors...

    public boolean openRead() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        boolean result = super.openRead(); // we are calling the parent's openRead() method to set up the Scanner sc object

        sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITERS);
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, there are other things that can prevent you from doing exactly this. For example, if the `sc` member was `private` scope, then the subclass could not use it directly in the manner I have shown.

In my example, `sc` uses `protected` access, so the class and its subclasses can use it.

In case there's a `private` `Scanner`, and assuming the parent has a `getScanner()` method that returns you the `Scanner`, you could do this:

```
    public boolean openRead() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        boolean result = super.openRead(); // we are calling the parent's openRead() method to set up the Scanner sc object
        Scanner sc = getScanner();
        sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITERS);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The sc member is private so i understand i would need to use a get method?

Comment: @user445714 - yes, if it is `private` then one option you have is to use a getter method to get access to the object.

Comment: is it possible to use the above openRead method with a getter inbetween the boolean results and the sc.useDelimiter?

Comment: @user445714 - check the newest code snippet at the bottom of my reply.

Comment: Right my understanding of this is, if there isnt getter on the parent side then the child side wont be able to see this if it is private? The child will have inherited it but cant see it?

Comment: @user445714 - if the parent has a `private` field then its children (and everyone else) won't be able to access it unless that class exposes an interface to get to that field. Check [Section 6.6 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6) - where it states `private` fields are NOT inherited by subclasses.